# Is there another way to print out a content using Jinja2 syntax?

Tags: flask, jinja2

I tried this code but it is not showing in my webpage

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{posts.content}}</h1>
        <p>{{posts.title}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's *post* not *postS* inside the double brackets.